# While searching each value the output is empty lists when sending POST request

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I used to find **form_data list** in the network then send POST requests but in this case there is not a such thing instead of that i take **requests payloads**. So, it seems like that method is not working.

This is the ***url of the site:*** https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/ebyn/vergiBorcu.html

The ***input:*** `<input ng-model="" voen="" placeholder="1234567891" type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty" id="voen">`

This is the code i have tried:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import json

request_headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en,en-GB;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '50',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Cookie': 'ETAXES=etaxes; JSESSIONID=C033E796031CA5C84A3A7B38E24330D4',
    'Host': 'www.e-taxes.gov.az',
    'Origin': 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az',
    'Referer': 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/ebyn/vergiBorcu.html',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',

}

taxid = {
    '8400260181',
    '1700393071',
    '1004199751',
    '2002283071',
}

payloads = {"METHOD": "wsEbynGetDebetSum",
            "voen": taxid,
            }

url = 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/ebyn/vergiBorcu.html'

for voen in taxid:
    payloads['voen'] = voen
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payloads), headers=request_headers)
    s = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    sContent = s.find('div', class_="col-sm-3").find_all("input", class_="form-control ng-pristine")
    print(voen)
    print(sContent)

with open('taxDebt.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter="\n")
    writer.writerow(sContent)
```

I expected to get an output like `Debt: "value"` but it returns empty lists:

```py
1700393071
[]
1004199751
[]
8400260181
[]
2002283071
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your `find` syntax is incorrect. You're looking for a tag that looks like `<div class="col-sm-3">`, in order to get that using BeautifulSoup, try this

```
s.find("div", class_="col-sm-3")
```

The `find_all` call also must be modified:

```
sContent = s.find('div', class_= "col-sm-3").find_all("input", class_= "form-control ng-pristine")
```

Comment: not working return error like this `1004199751
None
1300725461
None
8400260181
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrap/debtTax.py", line 46, in <module>
    writer.writerow(sContent)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType
`

Comment: That's a new issue. You have to fix your `find_all` method also the same way, otherwise it will just return `None` and you'll get errors when using `sContent`.

I'll edit my answer to show how I think it's done.

Comment: ERROR: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrap/debtTax.py", line 39, in <module>
    sContent = s.find('div', class_= "col-sm-3").find_all("input", class_= "form-control ng-pristine")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Comment: now it returns 
`8400260181
[]
1004199751
[]
1300725461
[]
` empty lists